# How to fire an event when a Knockout.js Template has been loaded

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, template-engine

I'm using the knockout external templating engine to create a section of my webpage. The template has a ul inside of it that I would like to perform a function on.

```
<ul id="myTags"></ul
```

So, for instance, once the template has been loaded from the server, I would like to call some method:

```
$("#myTags").doSomething(...)
```

How do I call this method once the template has been downloaded from the server, and inserted into the document? NOTE This may happen more than once....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `template` binding does have an `afterRender` callback that you could use to process the new elements: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_3_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove

I don't know what you want to do with your element, but I would consider using a custom binding for this purpose.  Custom bindings are described: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html and http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html

Even if you just use the `init` function of your custom binding, it will run every time that your template is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I'm doing this is using the jQuery livequery plugin:

```
    $('#myTags').livequery(doSomething);
```

Is there a better way?